# WebAPI Route defaults Guid.NewGuid()

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to generate the id as new Guid if the same is not provided in the route config, but it always generates the same NewGuid. Here is my code:

```cs
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "myroute",
    routeTemplate: "api/my/route/{userID}",
    defaults: new { controller = "my", userID = Guid.NewGuid() }
);
```

Here is the action method:

```cs
public string Post([FromBody]string value, Guid userID)
{
    return "Message Received for User: " + userID.ToString();
}
```

No matter how many time I call that method, I receive the same response, until unless I rebuild the code.

```cs
"Message Received for User: f90b2d6c-29f0-44a0-ba4d-aa72ac25d520"
```

Can someone please guide me whats happening here and how I can achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: The route configuration only happens once when the app starts. Thus you're generating one GUID, and storing it. Then it's always the default value until the app restarts.

Comment: Is the _userId_ in the URI ? If so, you should use `FromUri` instead of `FromBody`. Give it a try

Comment: @JamesR. thanks ... clears the confusion ... then can you please guide me how I can achieve the desired functionality as if I set that parameter to `RouteParameter.Optional` the routing is not able to match to that action and it throws error: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:31929/api/my/rout/'.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "desired functionality" is. But if you want a new GUID in that Post method, you're going to have to call Guid.NewGuid() again.

Comment: where exactly I have to call that as it is not reaching till the post action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ... solved the situation by adding another post method here is the final code:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "myroute",
    routeTemplate: "api/my/route/{userID}",
    defaults: new { controller = "my", userID = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

public string Post([FromBody]string value, Guid userID)
{
    return "Message Received for User: " + userID.ToString();
}

public string Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    Guid userID = Guid.NewGuid();
    return "Message Received for User: " + userID.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define the parameter as optional.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "myroute",
    routeTemplate: "api/my/route/{userID}",
    defaults: new { controller = "my", userID = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then in the action assign a value if non is given.

```
public string Post([FromBody]string value, Guid? userID)
{
    userID = userID ?? Guid.NewGuid();

    return "Message Received for User: " + userID.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I tried that but in this case it is throwing the error: No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'localhost:31929/api/my/route/

Comment: Did you define the Guid parameter as nullable `Guid?`

Comment: Yes ... I did the same :(